# Preventing direct zip file downloads in php

Tags: php

i want to protect direct download (copy/paste link)on my website.
 I am sending the download link in email, link is like  it is currently accessible on direct link  entry ,but  i want it to work only when email link is clicked and I know this can be done by checking the session variables but problem is that i do not have any login modules.

Comment: if people are not "lodged in", how do you know, who, and who can't, access a file?

Comment: i dont have any login modules on my website, i am serving the download link using emails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a special access token based on the client's IP if they have to download it within the same session.

e.g.

```
$downloadKey = md5($filename . '_' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$_SESSION[$downloadKey] = $downloadKey;
//  Include download link with key=$downloadKey
```

Then the PHP code that handles the download of the ZIP can re-hash the client IP and filename requested to see if it matches the session value.  If they match then the download can proceed.

```
$request = md5($requestedFilename . '_' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if (isset($_SESSION[$request]) && file_exists($requestedFilename)) { 
{
   // stream file
   unset($_SESSION[$request]);
}
else {
   // 401 unauthorized
}
```

This is assuming the zip file is not visible from the web already and that you are opening and streaming it from a PHP script.

Comment: I have to upvote this, it's another use case.

Comment: And in theory it would prevent link sharing between people (unless they're proxied of course).

Comment: @KrisOye Sorry I just realized you wrote the answer haha. Wouldn't they have to have same session id? So even if they were proxied, they would have to come from the same computer?

Comment: My 3 nightmares named: token/cookie/session stealing.

Comment: Yeah they would have to hijack the session.  And if you delete the token after the first download then re-use is not possible (first come, first served).

Comment: also sessions dont last for ever so they would have to com back in X minutes.

Comment: A nonce would also be ideal

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any "login modules" if you have emails/filenames (how you got these emails is another question)

simple: create unique link to (for example) https://example.com/download.php?file=ENCRYPTED_EMAIL_FILE_NAME for each email address+file name, send link.

download.php script decrypts clicked $_GET['file'], and sends it to browser with correct header. If decryption fails, show 404, log hack attempt or something like this.

If you don't have emails, well, maybe you should learn something about CMS/frameworks/databases/etc.

Comment: i am serving the download link  through emails ,thats how i got emails

Comment: I don't say you're spammer, or something, you just  need to have a predefined list of emails OR somehow register people on your site/ask them to provide their email during a session. )